# Latex beamer presentation page numbering in references section

Tags: beamer, bibtex

I am using `beamer` for presentation and `natbib` to display references at the end of presentation slides. However, by calling the following code,

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{refs}
```

all the references take about 6 pages but the total page number is not increasing because of the additional 6 pages of references, as if the references pages are not there.

Is there a way to keep the total page number updated (increased) with the added references?

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the problem by showing the page number instead of the frame number:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[pagenumber]


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t,allowframebreaks]
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
    A\\
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```